# Cannot create Sql Compact DB programmatically

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create an MVC4 application that affords the user to create a SQL Server Compact database on the fly.

Here is my code straight out of MSDN:

```
        string connStr = "Data Source = Test.sdf;";

        SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr);
        engine.CreateDatabase();
        engine.Dispose();
        SqlCeConnection conn = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 int, col2 ntext)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch { }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

But I receive this error:

**Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1914,File name = Test.sdf,SeCreateFile ]**

**Running VS 2012 in Admin mode will sove the problem, but will it work once this MVC app is compiled?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
        string connStr = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Test.sdf;";
```